# LINQ to SQL, select targets with max date

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, join, group-by

I ended up with this horrible code below, I can't get a better result now.
What is a better way of doing that?

It's about this part of my database:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

EDIT

A `Patient` has a `Subscription` to multiple `MonitoringObjects`. `Target` records refer to these `Subscriptions`. I want to retrieve the target records with the newest date per `Subscription` for a given `Patient` and a `Category` of `MonitoringObjects`. These target records may have different max dates, as `Targets` can be added for `Subscriptions` to `MonitoringsObjects` independently.

```
var subs = db.Subscriptions.Where(p => p.PatientID == patID).Where(p => p.MonitoringObject.Category.Name == "Medication");


var targets1 = from t in db.Targets
              where subs.Contains(t.Subscription)
              select t;

var maxTa = from t in db.Targets
            group t by t.SubscriptionID
                into g
                select new
                {
                    Ky = g.Key,
                    Date = g.Max(p => p.Date)
                };
var targets2 = from t in targets1
               where maxTa.Select(p => p.Ky).Contains( t.SubscriptionID ) && 
               maxTa.Select(p => p.Date).Contains( t.Date )
               select t;
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to select, exactly? Is it all Targets that have a Subscription in subs and have a Date field equal to the maximal value in this set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what this is trying to achieve, or what your datamodel looks like, but something like this?

```
var subs = db.Subscriptions.Where(p => p.PatientID == patID).Where(p => p.MonitoringObject.Category.Name == "Medication");

var targets = subs
    .SelectMany(s => s.Targets)
    .Where(t => t.Date == t.Subscription.Targets.Max(_t => _t.Date))
```

Comment: Please see picture of data model above.

Comment: @andreas: What is wrong with this solution? AHM beat me to it, but I would have suggested something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I think you added the diagram of the model while I was writing my answer so I missed it, but it looks like I expected. Is it because you don't have the relation properties? If so you could use the join syntax to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I'm just very tired... but I'll try your solution right now., thanks